# There is no nginx under usr/local path, so where is the default nginx server path?

Tags: nginx

Nginx directory is disexist under /usr/local.

My server's os is centos 7.2 64 bit.

> > error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn; pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
>
> events {
>       worker_connections  1024; }
>
> http {
>       include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
>       default_type  application/octet-stream;
>
> ```
> log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
>                   '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
>                   '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
>
> access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
>
> sendfile        on;
> #tcp_nopush     on;
>
> keepalive_timeout  65;
>
> #gzip  on;
>
> include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I found it by mysself.

> /usr/share/nginx/html